# Was my bios updated? Scary two minutes with black screen, system beeps and total unresponsiveness

Tags: boot, updates, uefi, bios, firmware

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with my Lenovo Thinkpad T460s. After an update a couple of weeks ago I did a reboot and I saw something which included the word "EFI" in the top left corner of my screen. Then everything went black and unresponsive.The laptop started system beeps every 5 seconds or so. I had no idea what was going on and tried to push the power button numerous times. I typed on the keyboard. Nothing. I was convinced something was terribly wrong. Nothing worked and since the laptop has a built in battery I could not cut power (probably a good thing in this case). After a couple of minutes the beeping stopped The laptop booted as normal. I had no idea what happened and whatever it was I was not given much forewarning or information. No way to see what it says while that message flashes by up in the screen corner.

I do know that a package with the word "firmware" in it was updated that day, but not exactly which one. I did check my bios and it's very new, from July 2018. I have not had Windows on this machine since I got it 18 months ago. I still wonder what this actually was. Anyone?

Update: I just read this about LVFS: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/08/lvfs-lenovo-firmware-updates-linux

Could that be what I experienced?

Answer (score 2):

A BIOS will never ever update itself and will only update when you tell it to do so. At the moment it requires a manual download, setting the download executable and follow the instructions for installing (sometimes you can load it from bios, others tell you to make a bootable medium).

Regarding the article: Lenovo *is joining* the Linux Vendor Firmware Service, better known as the LVFS. That is still in the future.

> The laptop started system beeps every 5 seconds or so

Beeps are an indication of hardware failure.  Here is a [list of hardware errors](https://support.lenovo.com/nl/en/solutions/ht062270) for Lenovo. But you need to also remember if those beeps are short or long ;)

> I do know that a package with the word "firmware" in it was updated that day

Most likely `linux-firmware` and that is "Firmware for Linux kernel drivers".

Comment: Thank you for answers. I am still wondering why this is showing in my biois settings: "UEFI Bios Date (Year-Month-Day  2018-07-09"? I have not had Windows on this machine since I got it 18 months ago, and I have never attempted to update the bios. Could that date mean something else?

Comment: There was another bios update today which I installed. I still do not understand how it got installed back in August after I had installed Ubuntu 18.04. I didn't even know about LVFS until a couple of days ago. This is great news for Linux/Thinkpad (and other supported hardware) who, like me, do not dual boot. The update today had a Lenovo logo and progress bar but the same beeps. The one that happened back in August was just a black screen with beeps.

Comment: I have not seen any automated bios updates. Only kernel modules related to bios but that is not the same ;)  So the question now is: did the version number or the date of your BIOS change?

Comment: Yes it did change. It changed to v 1.37: https://is.gd/hWFrnb Last week it went to 1.39 but that one I downloaded from the LVFS site. The upgrade from the downloaded image happened in the exaxt same way, but this time it was a progress bar and Lenovo logo but the system beeps were the same.